# static circle in openGL

Tags: opengl, geometry

I hope you can help me with a little problem...

I know how to draw a circle, that's not a problem - here is the code in c#

```
void DrawEllipse()
{
    GL.Color3(0.5, 0.6, 0.2);
    float x, y, z;
    double t;
    GL.Begin(BeginMode.Points);
    for (t = 0; t <= 360; t += 0.25)
    {
        x = (float)(3*Math.Sin(t));
        y = (float)(3*Math.Cos(t));
        z = (float)0;
        GL.Vertex3(x, y, z);
    }
    GL.End();

}
```

But there is a problem - when I Rotate 'Gl.Rotate(angle, axis)' and then redraw a circle - yeah, it's still circle in the 3D, but I want a circle in the screen - I mean static circle which is not rotating with 3D object in it... Is that possible? How to repair the code?

Comment: I have now, thanks for your help ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just draw it at a position before the camera!
Use `pushMatrix()` and `popMatrix()`.

Or you can draw the other things between `pushMatrix()` and `popMatrix()`. Then draw the circle.

Comment: Maybe this was a good help to put DrawEllipse() in the different part of the code, thanks a lot  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to draw a 2D circle on top of a 3D scene to create a HUD or similar?  If you are then you should research 2D OpenGL, glOrtho and using multiple viewports in a scene. There is a discussion around this here:
http://www.gamedev.net/topic/388298-opengl-hud/

Answer (score 0):

HUD (heads-up display): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HUD_(video_gaming)

```
void setupScene ()
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    // set the perspective
    glFrustum(...) // or glu's perspective
}


void loop ()
{
    // main scene
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glViewport (...)
    // push the camera position into GL_MODELVIEW
    // (i.e. the inverse matrix of its object position)

    // draw your normal 3D objects


    // switch to 2D projection (for the HUD)
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(....)

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    // draw the objects onto the HUD

    // switch back to 3d projection (i.e. restore GL_PROJECTION)
    // glEnable (GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPopMatrix();
    // glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    // swap buffers
}
```

The commented code is optional, depending on what you're gonna do in the end. Take it as hints.

Comment: it means to put DrawEllipse (or circle) in the different part of the code, I try to find where, and I was successful, thanks for help and your idea ;-)